# Every time I try to download Official videos from PYTUBE it shows this error

Tags: python, pytube

This is the Error that I always get whenever I tried to download any Official videos but the same video gets downloaded when using some online downloading app.

```
  KeyError    Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py in apply_descrambler(stream_data, key)
--> 297                 for format_item in formats
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    296                 }
--> 297                 for format_item in formats
    298             ]
KeyError: 'url'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-796467b30bec> in <module>
      7 import cv2
      8 
----> 9 video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tDq3fNew1rU')
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py in __init__(self, url, defer_prefetch_init, on_progress_callback, on_complete_callback, proxies)
     90         if not defer_prefetch_init:
     91             self.prefetch()
---> 92             self.descramble()
     94     def descramble(self) -> None:
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py in descramble(self)
    130             if not self.age_restricted and fmt in self.vid_info:
    131                 apply_descrambler(self.vid_info, fmt)
--> 132             apply_descrambler(self.player_config_args, fmt)
    134             if not self.js:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py in apply_descrambler(stream_data, key)
    299         except KeyError:
    300             cipher_url = [
--> 301                 parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
    302             ]
    303             stream_data[key] = [
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytube\extract.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    299         except KeyError:
    300             cipher_url = [
--> 301                 parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
    302             ]
    303             stream_data[key] = [

KeyError: 'cipher'
```

so can anybody help me in solving this error

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code you're using?

Comment: `from pytube import YouTube
import os

video = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epwpvDCRhzw&t=1s')


print(video.title)
print(video.thumbnail_url)

video.streams.filter(adaptive = True).all()

itag = int(input("Enter an itag here: "))
video.streams.get_by_itag(itag).download('C:/Users/test/')`

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. I solved it by doing:

1. goto `site-packages/pytub/extract.py` where `pytube` was installed.
2. find the line: `parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)`
3. replace `["cipher"]` to `["signatureCipher"]`
4. done.

source [here](https://github.com/nficano/pytube/issues/591).

Comment: I tried but no success same error with "signatureCipher" intead of "cipher"

Answer (score 0):

```
#TODO: Actually due to some sudden changes on youtube some changes have to made on this API too..
# ? just use this line before starting any pytube script:
# ! pytube.__main__.apply_descrambler = __pre__.apply_descrambler

# The below imports are required by the patch
import json
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, unquote

# This function is based off on the changes made in
# https://github.com/nficano/pytube/pull/643

    def apply_descrambler(stream_data, key):
        """Apply various in-place transforms to YouTube's media stream data.
        Creates a ``list`` of dictionaries by string splitting on commas, then
        taking each list item, parsing it as a query string, converting it to a
        ``dict`` and unquoting the value.
        :param dict stream_data:
            Dictionary containing query string encoded values.
        :param str key:
            Name of the key in dictionary.
        **Example**:
        >>> d = {'foo': 'bar=1&var=test,em=5&t=url%20encoded'}
        >>> apply_descrambler(d, 'foo')
        >>> print(d)
        {'foo': [{'bar': '1', 'var': 'test'}, {'em': '5', 't': 'url encoded'}]}
        """
        otf_type = "FORMAT_STREAM_TYPE_OTF"
    
        if key == "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map" and not stream_data.get(
            "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"
        ):
            formats = json.loads(stream_data["player_response"])["streamingData"]["formats"]
            formats.extend(
                json.loads(stream_data["player_response"])["streamingData"][
                    "adaptiveFormats"
                ]
            )
            try:
                stream_data[key] = [
                    {
                        "url": format_item["url"],
                        "type": format_item["mimeType"],
                        "quality": format_item["quality"],
                        "itag": format_item["itag"],
                        "bitrate": format_item.get("bitrate"),
                        "is_otf": (format_item.get("type") == otf_type),
                    }
                    for format_item in formats
                ]
            except KeyError:
                cipher_url = []
                for data in formats:
                    cipher = data.get("cipher") or data["signatureCipher"]
                    cipher_url.append(parse_qs(cipher))
                stream_data[key] = [
                    {
                        "url": cipher_url[i]["url"][0],
                        "s": cipher_url[i]["s"][0],
                        "type": format_item["mimeType"],
                        "quality": format_item["quality"],
                        "itag": format_item["itag"],
                        "bitrate": format_item.get("bitrate"),
                        "is_otf": (format_item.get("type") == otf_type),
                    }
                    for i, format_item in enumerate(formats)
                ]
        else:
            stream_data[key] = [
                {k: unquote(v) for k, v in parse_qsl(i)}
                for i in stream_data[key].split(",")
            ]
```

This file was released in one of the issues (in pytube GitHub) just import it every time on your main file and then `pytube.__main__.apply_descrambler = __pre__.apply_descrambler`
use that line on your file.

This detects cipher or the cipher signature and makes some neccees.. changes